# Issue returning stream when it's part of a subclass

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I have a WCF method:

```
public Stream GetFile(string systemName, string version, string type)
{
    //Code omitted for brevity
    return File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}
```

This works and returns me a valid file I can save on the other end.

I am trying to change the method to this:

```
public GetFileStreamResult GetFile(string systemName, string version, string type)
{
    //Code omitted for brevity
    var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return new GetFileStreamResult
    {
        Stream = fs,
        Checksum = fs.GenerateCheckSum()
    };
}
```

Where `GetFileStreamResult` is:

```
[DataContract]
public class GetFileStreamResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public Stream Stream { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Checksum { get; set; }
}
```

When I do this though, I am receiving the following error:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:64175/UpdateService.svc. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details.

Examples I find online about returning `Stream`s only ever return the stream, not an object containing a stream so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you stepped through the code in the refactored method.. where you have `Stream = fs` when you get to the Checksum line, is fs null...? if so then that's your problem. also where are you defining `path`

Comment: Yes, I've stepped through it and `fs` is valid and not null. Path is set further up and is correct (the file is opened and the result I'm sending is correct and has a checksum generated).

Comment: Will `byte[]` work for you (if you have small files)? I really doubt you can mix serializable and non-serializable objects in the [DataContract] object.

Comment: Hm, good point. In this case, byte[] would work (feel free to add an answer). Do you know of any reference I can use to work out what I'm doing wrong with this way though? Are there other contract attributes that could be used instead?